# Which algorithm would you use to solve a multiple producer-consumer problem with constraints?

Tags: genetic-algorithms, optimization

I'm solving this problem similar to consumer-producer of materials (i.e. sand).

This is the graph of the problem:

[image]

Where `Req` (`E0` and `E1`) are units that require material, and `Prod` (`C0` and `C1`) produce material. I'm looking for the first random solution or similar that meets the constraints i.e `E0` Require `10`, shared from `C0` or/and `C1`.

What would be a valid approach? 
I just think in Genetic Algorithms.